# Configuring external master GCP errors

Tags: replication, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm following the GCP tutorial to configure an external master.

The external master is a mysql 5.6 db hosted on a Google Compute Engine running ubuntu 14.04.

The API is enable, the dump has been created according to google tutorial.
The internal master is created successfully, the replication commands run and starts the replication process.

After one hour, the Console shows that the replica is still in creation (my dump was 69Mb therefore I doubt it makes it that slow).

I checked the google logs and I found this:

```
 textPayload: "2017-03-02 08:03:22 591904 [Note] Check error log for additional messages. You will not be able to start replication until the issue is resolved and the server restarted."
```

And then below I find several error messages:

```
"2017-03-02 08:03:22 591904 [ERROR] Failed to create or recover replication info repository."   
 "2017-03-02 08:03:22 591904 [ERROR] Error creating relay log info: Error checking repositories."   
"2017-03-02 08:03:22 591904 [ERROR] Error in checking mysql.slave_relay_log_info repository info type of TABLE."
"2017-03-02 08:03:22 591904 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them"
```

I am confused because the documentation clearly says that the mysql table shouldn't be dumped, but it looks like it fails creating it.

I could suppose that these are normally thrown errors resolved during the replica creation, but now that it runs for a few hours I start to doubt that it will ever work.... any idea about the underlying issue?

Comment: The issue with external master was fixed in middle April, so if you still have some issues configuring it, I'll recommend opening a public issue tracker in [here](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Here the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/35907433) where it was reported as fixed.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier Were you able to configure MySQL external master. If so, please write a self-answer so to help the other community experiencing similar problem and if you are still having problem, report this issue on [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)